# Exception Adding elements to a JList

Tags: java, swing, exception, netbeans, jlist

I'm writing code to retrieve data from a MySQL database.
I want to add one column of the query to a JList.

This is my code:

```
    try {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
        db = new Database();
        db.connect();
        Statement st = db.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT nombre FROM alumnos");

        while (rs.next()) {
            names.add(rs.getString("nombre"));
        }

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        for(String nms : names) {
            listModel.addElement(nms);
        }

        //This is the line 140
        // and lstInicio is the JList
        lstInicio.setModel(listModel);

    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.err.println(sql.getMessage());
    }
```

I think everything is ok, but when I reach this part of the code I get an Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at proyecto.ausentismo.MainWindow.loadList(MainWindow.java:140)
at proyecto.ausentismo.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:21)
at proyecto.ausentismo.Login.btnLoginActionPerformed(Login.java:121)
at proyecto.ausentismo.Login.access$000(Login.java:11)
at proyecto.ausentismo.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicButtonListener.java:303)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Does anybody know what is causing this exception? How could I find out?
**EDIT:** I commented the line of the error. And stil get the Exception

Comment: Can you add a comment to your code block which points out which line is MainWindow line 140 (which the error trace says is the source of the exception)?

Comment: I second what @Arkanon requests. If the error is in the code above, my bet is on this line: `lstInicio.setModel(listModel);` and that `lstInicio` is null. If so, then you're not properly initializing this variable before using it.

Comment: He must be lacking Object creation in his code `DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();`

Comment: I coomented the line so you can see exactly where is the Exception from.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, your `lstInicio` variable is null. The solution: look back into your code to find out where you think that you initialized it, and to see why it didn't actually get initialized. That's about all we can say based on what you've posted so far.

---

Edit:  @jesuscc29: glad you've got it working. The key lesson here is not so much the answer to the specific problem that you're having, but rather the general process of debugging a NullPointerException (NPE), since I can guarantee that you'll run into these buggers time and time again. Always first find out which line, and then which variable on that line is causing the NPE to occur, and then try to trace back into your code to see why the variable is null. Do this, and 90% of the time you'll find the problem and it's solution.

Comment: OMG!.. I know where is my mistake, i was calling my method on the class constructor, but i was calling before the `initComponents();` and of course `lstInicio` was null. But anyways, thank you all for the answers!.

Comment: @jesuscc29: glad you've got it working. The key lesson here is not so much the answer to the specific problem that you're having, but rather the general process of debugging a NullPointerException (NPE), since I can guarantee that you'll run into these buggers time and time again. Always first find out which line, and then which variable on that line is causing the NPE to occur, and then try to trace back into your code to see why the variable is null. Do this, and 90% of the time you'll find the problem and it's solution. Best of luck!